# JavaFX 3d samples

Tags: java, netbeans, 3d, javafx

I have just started with Java and the first thing i did was to download the Java SE JDK 7u40 bundled with Netbeans.
I am on ubuntu 13.04.
When i tried out the samples from JavaFX  on Netbeans specifically the Cube3D sample when i ran it strange results came out.I had an empty window with small yellow square on the top left of the window 
rather than a 3d Cube on the window.
Similar problems occur with all the samples that have 3d in them.
However when i do this on windows enviroment everything runs properly (windows 7 to be precise).
Someone any reason of why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this page contains the answer:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html

It states that: ...On Linux platforms, graphic hardware acceleration is only supported for Nvidia cards (proprietary drivers only).

Cheers.